# Cannot improve model accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am building a general-purpose NN that would classify images (Dog/No Dog) and movie reviews(Good/Bad). I have to stick to a very specific architecture and loss function so changing these two seems out of the equation. My architecture is a two-layer network with relu followed by a sigmoid and a cross-entropy loss function. With 1000 epochs and a learning rate of around .001 I am getting 100 percent training accuracy and .72 testing accuracy.I was looking for suggestions to improve my testing accuracy.This is the layout of what I have:

```
def train_net(epochs,batch_size,train_x,train_y,model_size,lr):
  n_x,n_h,n_y=model_size
  model = Net(n_x, n_h, n_y)
  optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.005)
  loss_function = nn.BCELoss() 
  train_losses = []
  accuracy = []
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    count=0
    model.train() 
    train_loss = []
    batch_accuracy = []
    for idx in range(0, train_x.shape[0], batch_size):

      batch_x = torch.from_numpy(train_x[idx : idx + batch_size]).float() 
      batch_y = torch.from_numpy(train_y[:,idx : idx + batch_size]).float()    
      model_output = model(batch_x) 
      batch_accuracy=[]  
      loss = loss_function(model_output, batch_y) 
      train_loss.append(loss.item())

      preds = model_output > 0.5
      nb_correct = (preds == batch_y).sum()
      count+=nb_correct.item()                            
      optim.zero_grad()
      loss.backward()
# Scheduler made it worse 
# scheduler.step(loss.item())  
  optim.step()

    if epoch % 100 == 1:
      train_losses.append(train_loss)
      print("Iteration : {}, Training loss: {} ,Accuracy %: {}".format(epoch,np.mean(train_loss),(count/train_x.shape[0])*100))              
  plt.plot(np.squeeze(train_losses))
  plt.ylabel('loss')
  plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
  plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(lr))
  plt.show()
  return model
```

My model parameters:

```
batch_size = 32
lr = 0.0001
epochs = 1500

n_x = 12288     # num_px * num_px * 3
n_h = 7
n_y = 1
model_size=n_x,n_h,n_y
model=train_net(epochs,batch_size,train_x,train_y,model_size,or)
```

and this is the testing phase.

```
model.eval()  #Setting the model to eval mode, hence making it deterministic.
test_loss = []
count=0;
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

for idx in range(0, test_x.shape[0], batch_size):
  with torch.no_grad():   
    batch_x = torch.from_numpy(test_x[idx : idx + batch_size]).float() 
    batch_y = torch.from_numpy(test_y[:,idx : idx + batch_size]).float()
    model_output = model(batch_x)
    preds = model_output > 0.5
    loss = loss_function(model_output, batch_y)
    test_loss.append(loss.item())
    nb_correct = (preds == batch_y).sum()
    count+=nb_correct.item()  

print("test loss: {},test accuracy: {}".format(np.mean(test_loss),count/test_x.shape[0]))
```

Things I have tried:
Messing around with the learning rate, having momentum, using schedulers and changing batch sizes.Of course these were mainly guesses and not based on any valid assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is **overfitting**. With 100% accuracy on the training set, your model is effectively memorizing the training set, then failing to **generalize** to unseen samples. The good news is this is a very common major challenge!

You need regularization. One method is **dropout**, whereby on different training epochs a random set of the NN connections are dropped, forcing the network to "learn" alternate pathways and weights, and softening sharp peaks in parameter space. Since you need to keep your architecture and loss function the same, you won't be able to add such an option in (though for completeness, read [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-and-dropout-in-neural-networks-explained-with-pytorch-47d7a8459bcd) for a description and implementation of dropout in PyTorch).

Given your constraints, you'll want to use something like **L2 or L1 weight regularization**. This typically shows up in the way of adding an additional term to the cost/loss function, which penalizes large weights. In PyTorch, **L2 regularization** is implemented via the `torch.optim` construct, with the option `weight_decay`. (See documentation: [torch.optim](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html), search for 'L2')

For your code, try something like:

```
def train_net(epochs,batch_size,train_x,train_y,model_size,lr):
  ...
  optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),...,weight_decay=0.01)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. My loss got stuck and is not moving from where it got stuck.

Comment: Interesting! Have you tried regularizing? If your model reached 100% accuracy on the training set, there would be no more room to change the loss, as you've found the global optimum for your given dataset given your parameters. If this is the case, you've memorized the set perfectly, which isn't ideal and doesn't generalize. Is this what's happened? Could you post a plot of your loss and accuracy overlaid?

Comment: @Aliman If you found this response valuable (or the other), would you mind selecting it as a suitable answer to your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your statement that your training accuracy is 100%, while your testing accuracy is significantly lower at 72%, it seems that you are significantly **overfitting** your dataset.

In short, this means that your model is training itself too specifically to the training data that you've given it, picking up on quirks that may exist in the training data but which are not inherent to the classification. For example, if  the dogs in your training data were all white, the model would eventually learn to associate the color white with dogs, and be hard-pressed to recognize dogs of other colors given to it in the test data set.

There are many avenues to address this issue: a well sourced overview of the subject written in simple terms can be found [here.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-regularization-to-reduce-overfitting-and-improve-generalization-error/)

Without more information on the specific constraints you have around changing the architecture of the neural network, it's tough to say for sure what you will and will not be able to change. However, weight regularization and dropout are often used to great effect (and are described in the above article.) You should also be free to implement early stopping and a weight constraint to the model.

I'll leave it you to find resources on how to implement these specific strategies in pytorch, but this should provide a good jumping off point.

Comment: "*I'll leave it you to find resources on how to implement these specific strategies in pytorch*" - OP provide their code, so some code suggestions on this should be part of a good answer; otherwise you are largely repeating stuff from the linked article, and the link itself in a comment would be enough.